# Associate Facebook Account With Multiple Users in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In my application I use parse's services to connect users to Facebook. When a user tries to connect to an facebook account that is already linked to another user in the app, an error is given and the user is not allowed to connect. Since I am using anonymous users in my app, this is a particular problem if the user deletes the app and reinstalls, as their old account still exists in the database connected to their facebook account, but they now have a new anonymous user account, and cannot link the new account to facebook.

What is the best way for me to fix this problem? If I'm not mistaken, there is no way to tell when a user deletes your application, so I can't delete the old user from the database when the app is deleted. 
I need a way to either log out the old user and log in the new user when a new user tries to connect to facebook or to allow multiple users to be linked to the same facebook account. Or I suppose to merge the new anonymous user account into the old one that is linked with Facebook.

Anyways, has anybody had an issue like this and found a good solution?

Comment: When the user tries to connect to Facebook but has already another account linked to it, the request fails, that's clear. BUT, is the request returning the FacebookId somewhere? You could then delete the specific user in your userbase and retry connecting with Facebook again.